# GeoNetwork installation with Tomcat9 on Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, geonetwork, tomcat

I am trying to install GeoNetwork WAR file on Tomcat 9. I have placed the file in webapps folder. It failed to start with error log as below. I have tried with Java version 8 and 11, got same error with both the versions.

```
2020-08-10 16:42:33,093 ERROR [jeeves] - JeevesContextLoaderListener: Error creating bean with name 'org.fao.geonet.kernel.datamanager.draft.DraftMetadataIndexer#0': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'searchManager': Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.fao.geonet.kernel.datamanager.draft.DraftMetadataIndexer#0': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'searchManager': Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(JeevesContextLoaderListener.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.geotools.xml.Schemas.parse(Schemas.java:302)
    at org.geotools.xml.Schemas.parse(Schemas.java:294)
    at org.geotools.xml.Schemas.parse(Schemas.java:256)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GML.buildSchema(GML.java:2732)
    at org.geotools.xml.XSD.getSchema(XSD.java:232)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GML.<init>(GML.java:71)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GML.<clinit>(GML.java:55)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GMLConfiguration.<init>(GMLConfiguration.java:122)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GMLConfiguration.<init>(GMLConfiguration.java:114)
    at org.geotools.filter.v2_0.FESConfiguration.<init>(FESConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.SearchManager.<clinit>(SearchManager.java:157)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.geotools.styling.StyleFactory is not an ImageIO SPI class
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.checkClassAllowed(ServiceRegistry.java:722)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:117)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.<init>(FactoryRegistry.java:155)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.<init>(FactoryCreator.java:91)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getServiceRegistry(CommonFactoryFinder.java:76)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.lookup(CommonFactoryFinder.java:346)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(CommonFactoryFinder.java:300)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(CommonFactoryFinder.java:390)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(CommonFactoryFinder.java:404)
    at org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.<clinit>(DataUtilities.java:205)
    ... 84 more
2020-08-10 16:42:33,109 FATAL [jeeves.engine] - Raised exception during init
2020-08-10 16:42:33,110 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Exception : org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.fao.geonet.kernel.datamanager.draft.DraftMetadataIndexer#0': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'searchManager': Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2020-08-10 16:42:33,110 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Message   : Error creating bean with name 'org.fao.geonet.kernel.datamanager.draft.DraftMetadataIndexer#0': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'searchManager': Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2020-08-10 16:42:33,116 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Stack     : org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.fao.geonet.kernel.datamanager.draft.DraftMetadataIndexer#0': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'searchManager': Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at jeeves.config.springutil.JeevesContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(JeevesContextLoaderListener.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5146)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1849)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SearchManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/core-3.10.3-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.geotools.xml.Schemas.parse(Schemas.java:302)
    at org.geotools.xml.Schemas.parse(Schemas.java:294)
    at org.geotools.xml.Schemas.parse(Schemas.java:256)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GML.buildSchema(GML.java:2732)
    at org.geotools.xml.XSD.getSchema(XSD.java:232)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GML.<init>(GML.java:71)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GML.<clinit>(GML.java:55)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GMLConfiguration.<init>(GMLConfiguration.java:122)
    at org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GMLConfiguration.<init>(GMLConfiguration.java:114)
    at org.geotools.filter.v2_0.FESConfiguration.<init>(FESConfiguration.java:116)
    at org.fao.geonet.kernel.search.SearchManager.<clinit>(SearchManager.java:157)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.geotools.styling.StyleFactory is not an ImageIO SPI class
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.checkClassAllowed(ServiceRegistry.java:722)
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.<init>(ServiceRegistry.java:117)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryRegistry.<init>(FactoryRegistry.java:155)
    at org.geotools.factory.FactoryCreator.<init>(FactoryCreator.java:91)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getServiceRegistry(CommonFactoryFinder.java:76)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.lookup(CommonFactoryFinder.java:346)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory(CommonFactoryFinder.java:300)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(CommonFactoryFinder.java:390)
    at org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2(CommonFactoryFinder.java:404)
    at org.geotools.data.DataUtilities.<clinit>(DataUtilities.java:205)
    ... 84 more
```

Answer (score -1):

GeoNetwork requires a Java 8 (JRE) environment.
Copy the `geonetwork.war` to `/var/lib/tomcat9/webapp` and edit files:

- /var/lib/tomcat9/webapp/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-node/srv.xm
- /var/lib/tomcat9/webapp/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/jdbc.properties

Comment: The answer is very incomplete, Please specify what things have to edit